# Юнит-тестирование Activity и Fragment

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты, тестирование, junit

Как известно из коробки в Android Studio для юнит-тестов поставляется JUnit.

JUnit позволяет без проблем протестировать "не визуальные" классы. Но, что делать с `Activity` и `Fragment`? Ведь мало того, что они реализуют UI, их жизненным циклом управляет система.

Также возникает вопрос получения контекста в таких тестах. Когда тестируется обычный класс в рамках инструментального теста получить контекст можно без труда при помощи стандартного способа, который приводится в образце теста из коробки. Но, как быть в случае `Activity` и `Fragment`?

Comment: Тестирование UI делают с помощью [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso). В общем всё о тестировании можно узнать начиная с этой страницы: https://developer.android.com/training/testing